# Accessing dgemm in C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I need to implement a matrix class in C++ and one of the operations must be matrix multiplication via dgemm. My professor had done an example in class in C, but for some reason I can't get it to work in C++. This is my header file matrix.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
#include "blas.h"
}

[blah blah blah, matrix class here; overloaded * operator will do the matrix      
multiplication]

matrix operator* (const matrix &other){

matrix AxB(Nrows, other.Ncolumns, "(" + name + "*" + "other.name" + ")");

char TRANSA = 'N';
char TRANSB = 'N';
int M = Nrows;
int N = other.Ncolumns;
int K = Ncolumns;
double alpha = 1.;
double beta = 0.;

dgemm_ (&TRANSA,
        &TRANSB,
        &M,
        &N,
        &K,
        &alpha,
        data,
        &M,
        other.data,
        &K,
        &beta,
        AxB.data,
        &M);

return AxB;

[blah blah blah, overloaded = operator here; i'm positive this is not the problem 
 since it works for matrix addition]
```

Main function:

```
#include "matrix.h"

main(){

// entries of A and B are randomized between 0 and 1
matrix A(5,5);
matrix B(5,5);

matrix C = A*B;

}
```

Now the blas.h header file:

```
void dgemm_ (char *TRANSA,
             char *TRANSB,
             int *M,
             int *N,
             int *K,
             double *ALPHA,
             double **A,
             int *LDA,
             double **B,
             int *LDB,
             double *BETA,
             double **C,
             int *LDC);
```

I'm to use the subroutine outlined here: http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemm.f

Basically, the way we did it in class for the C implementation built a matrix as one long array using (double*) calloc(rows*columns, sizeof(double)).

My C++ implemenation does:

```
double **data;

data = new double[rows];

for(int i=1; i<=rows; ++i){
    data[i-1] = new double[columns];
}
```

and then I can index using data[i][j]. But since the dgemm subroutine is supposed to take in double *A, double *B, etc. but my matrices are double **A and so on, how do I fix this?

This is the error message I get from valgrind:

```
==18845== Invalid write of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4165C1C: ATL_dgezero (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149DA7: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas   
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d680 is 8 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==18845==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind   
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18845==    by 0x8049045: dmatrix::dmatrix(int, int, std::string) (dmatrix.hpp:77)
==18845==    by 0x8049532: dmatrix::operator*(dmatrix const&) (dmatrix.hpp:218)
==18845==    by 0x8048DCB: main (main.cpp:17)
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid write of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4165C1F: ATL_dgezero (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149DA7: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas   
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d678 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==18845==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind 
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18845==    by 0x8049045: dmatrix::dmatrix(int, int, std::string) (dmatrix.hpp:77)
==18845==    by 0x8049532: dmatrix::operator*(dmatrix const&) (dmatrix.hpp:218)
==18845==    by 0x8048DCB: main (main.cpp:17)
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid write of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4165C22: ATL_dgezero (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149DA7: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas    
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d690 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid write of size 8 
==18845==    at 0x4165C25: ATL_dgezero (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149DA7: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d688 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid read of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4143D60: ATL_dJIK0x0x0NN0x0x0_aX_bX (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149A9D: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478cf80 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid read of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4143D64: ATL_dJIK0x0x0NN0x0x0_aX_bX (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149A9D: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas    
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d130 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==18845==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind 
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18845==    by 0x8049045: dmatrix::dmatrix(int, int, std::string) (dmatrix.hpp:77)
==18845==    by 0x8048D49: main (main.cpp:6)
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid read of size 8 
==18845==    at 0x4143D4C: ATL_dJIK0x0x0NN0x0x0_aX_bX (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149A9D: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d678 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==18845==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind 
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18845==    by 0x8049045: dmatrix::dmatrix(int, int, std::string) (dmatrix.hpp:77)
==18845==    by 0x8049532: dmatrix::operator*(dmatrix const&) (dmatrix.hpp:218)
==18845==    by 0x8048DCB: main (main.cpp:17)
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid write of size 8
==18845==    at 0x4143D93: ATL_dJIK0x0x0NN0x0x0_aX_bX (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4149A9D: ATL_dNCmmJIK (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x415BE8E: ATL_dgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4182F54: ATL_dptgemm_nt (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas 
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4183140: ATL_dptgemm (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x40818F6: atl_f77wrap_dgemm_ (in /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas   
/libblas.so.3gf.0)
==18845==    by 0x4E4E0004: ???
==18845==  Address 0x478d678 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==18845==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind 
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18845==    by 0x8049045: dmatrix::dmatrix(int, int, std::string) (dmatrix.hpp:77)
==18845==    by 0x8049532: dmatrix::operator*(dmatrix const&) (dmatrix.hpp:218)
==18845==    by 0x8048DCB: main (main.cpp:17)
==18845== 
==18845== Invalid read of size 8
==18845==    at 0x8048DEA: main (main.cpp:19)
==18845==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18845== 
==18845== 
==18845== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18845==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==18845==    at 0x8048DEA: main (main.cpp:19)
==18845==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==18845==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==18845==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==18845==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==18845==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==18845== 
==18845== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18845==     in use at exit: 3,581 bytes in 39 blocks
==18845==   total heap usage: 49 allocs, 10 frees, 7,760 bytes allocated
==18845== 
==18845== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18845==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 4 blocks
==18845==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18845==      possibly lost: 88 bytes in 4 blocks
==18845==    still reachable: 3,365 bytes in 31 blocks
==18845==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18845== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18845== 
==18845== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18845== ERROR SUMMARY: 111 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

up until I try to implement the dgemm matrix multiplication, I get no errors and no leaks, so I'm pretty sure all my troubles lie with the dgemm implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layout of the C version is different from the memory layout in your C++ version. As BLAS expects the kind of layout used by the C version, your C++ version won't work.

Thus, you need to allocate a big 1-D array in your C++ version as well; you could overload operator() in order to get indexing for 2D arrays. Or for production code, use a library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org).

Comment: Hmm, that's what I figured, thanks. I think I'll just go back and change my indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't realize hitting enter while responding would send the response.

I changed the indexing:

```
double *data;

data = new double[rows*columns];
```

then every time I want to index it I just to data[(i-1)*columns + (j-1)] for row-major indexing. The The code definitely works now, and compiles with 0 errors and 0 memory leaks! The only thing is that I get a completely gibberish result now.

Does this have to do with the fact that fortran does column-major ordering whereas I'm doing row-major? How would I reconcile this?

Comment: Set TRANSA and TRANSB to 'Y'. Then dgemm will consider the input arrays to be transposed.